# "No data exists for the row/column" when connecting to SQL database from VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb, datareader

I'm trying to create a program which has a datagridview, when the user clicks on a cell in the view, it then looks in a SQL database, grabs information from other fields in the same record, and automatically fills corresponding text boxes (done by manipulating the name of the field) in the form.

For some reason however, I'm getting an error message saying:
"InvalidOperationException was unhandled"
"No Data exists for the row / column"

Here is the code relevant to this part of the program:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgvResults.CellMouseClick
    ' Set values in the text boxes to both corresponding to the film.
    Dim strFields() As String = {"ID", "fName", "fGenre", "fSynopsis", "fAgeRating", "fActorsActresses", "fWebRating", "fNoReservations", "fWeeksRunning"}

    Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ApplicationData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    Con.Open() 'Open the connection
    Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand(StringBuilderCommand("*", "Films", dgvResults.CurrentCell.Value, "fName"), Con) 'Create a string by calling the StringBuilderCommand to combine the parameters together with quotes.

    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim Rdr As OleDbDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Dim intCount As Integer = 4 ' Create a loop variable.
    Do While Rdr.Read() Or intCount < 6 ' While this statement is 'TRUE', e.g. there is a valid record.

        strResult = "txt" & strFields(intCount).Replace("f", "") 'Remove any instances of 'f', e.g. the prefix of the string.

        txtActorsActresses.Text = StringBuilderCommand("*", "Films", dgvResults.CurrentCell.Value, "fName")
        Me.Controls(strResult).Text = Rdr.Item(strFields(intCount)) ' Suspect the error lies here.

        'Set the text-box to the correct value from the database.
        'This will allow me to go through several text boxes, and grab their corresponding values from the database.

        intCount = intCount + 1

        'Current error is because it cannot find any data beyond the first field taken.
        'I have no idea why this is. But if I change the starting intCount value, it will successfully take a different value.
    Loop

    Rdr.Close() 'Cleaning up.
    Cmd.Dispose()
    Con.Close()

    WebBrowser1.Navigate(dgvResults.CurrentCell.Value.Replace(" ", ".") & ".movie.poster.new.jpg.to") 'Grab the movie poster off the internet corresponding to the films name.
End Sub

Private Function StringBuilderCommand(Field, Table, CurrentCellValue, SearchParameter)
    'Creates a suitable SQL string.
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder("SELECT ")
    MyStringBuilder.Append("*") ' Append the parameter 'Field'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append(" FROM ") ' Append the SQL command 'FROM'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append(Table) ' Append the parameter 'Table'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append(" WHERE ") ' Append the SQL command 'WHERE'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append(SearchParameter) ' Append the parameter 'SearchParameter'.
    MyStringBuilder.Append("=""")
    MyStringBuilder.Append(CurrentCellValue) ' Append the parameter 'CurrentCellValue', representing the cell selected.
    MyStringBuilder.Append("""") 'Append a quotation mark.

    Return MyStringBuilder.ToString() ' Return it to the main program.

End Function
```

Database table being connected to: [image: http://i.imgur.com/rN0zFwG.png]

A view of the error as it looks in Visual Studio 2012 Express: [image: http://i.imgur.com/9QOQHI1.png]

The value of 'dgvResults.CurrentCell.Value' is the name of a film taken from the database (e.g. "12 Years a Slave").

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
C.

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive: make sure that the column/row you are trying to access exists at all in your DB.

Comment: I think in  Do While Rdr.Read() Or intCount < 6 you need AND and not OR

Comment: Good point by Kostas... why you want to continue reading beyond what can be read?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the value of strFields(intCount) you are passing to the reader. It is not a valid column index.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to loop on the fields before looping again on `DataReader()`, like:

```
Do While Rdr.Read()

    For intCount as Integer = 4 to 6
      strResult = "txt" & strFields(intCount).Replace("f", "")
      txtActorsActresses.Text = StringBuilderCommand("*", "Films", dgvResults.CurrentCell.Value, "fName")
      Me.Controls(strResult).Text = Rdr.Item(strFields(intCount))
    Next

Loop
```

I removed the `Dim intCount As Integer = 4` because it is no longer needed because of the `for next` loop.